# The length of GROUP must equal the number of rows in TRAINING

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Currently i am trying to use knn classifier to classify the image as an original image or forged image.`

load facevalustesting.mat

```
load facevalusf.mat
```

load facevaluso.mat

A=facevalustesting;

B=[ facevaluso;

facevalusf ];

G={'Original Image';

'Forged Image'};

class=knnclassify(A,B,G);

But at the time of execution i get an error as The length of GROUP must equal the number of rows in TRAINING.....
I want to know whats the problem in this.
 `

Comment: check the documentation. http://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnclassify.html?refresh=true
What size are your matrices facevaluso and facevalusf?

Comment: facevalusf=7*256   and  facevalustesting.=1*256

Comment: Is it necessary that my training and sample should contain same number of rows????

Comment: B must have the same number of rows as G has entries. 
So if G only has two entries ('Original' and 'Forged') then you cannot have more than two rows in B (you have 10 + whatever rownumber facevalusf has).
I guess you are trying to compare two images and then want your class variable to be 'Forged' or 'Original', however, this is not what knnclassify is intended to do. Instead it compares the rows of B to the rows of A and then tells you which ones are closest matches.